# Is there a better way to index a large array using a conditional statement than np.where?

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial

Sorry for the wall of text.  I tried to shorten it, but I think everything will be helpful to someone who is willing to read it all.

I have xyz point clouds and I'm trying to grid them into DEMs  (digital elevation models if you're unfamiliar - just 2D arrays of elevations).  My DEMs need to have significantly lower resolution (rather, they don't need nearly as high of a resolution) as my point cloud, so there are on the order of 10 points in my point cloud per DEM cell.  My code iterates over rows and columns of the final DEM and calculates an elevation value for each cell based on the XYZ coordinates supplied.  To do this, I specify a grid size and spacing and then the code calculates the x and y maxima and minima for each grid cell.  Then, it finds z all of the z values where x and y are within the maxima and minima of that cell, rejects outliers and takes the mean of the remaining values to determine the final value for that cell.  xyz values are stored in an array that looks like this:

```
xyz = np.array([[x1, y1, z1],
                [x2, y2, z2],
                [x3, y3, z3]])       #     with tens of thousands of xyz cominations
```

My current method involves creating a list of cell boundary values in X and Y and then adding all z values that have x and y values within the boundaries to a list of elevations:

```
dx = 0.5           # cell size in meters

xmin = np.min(xyz[:,0])
xmax = np.max(xyz[:,0])
ymin = np.min(xyz[:,1])
ymax = np.max(xyz[:,1])
xoffset = ((xmax-xmin) % dx)/2.0
yoffset = ((ymax-ymin) % dx)/2.0


xlims = np.arange(xmin+xoffset, xmax, dx)   # list of grid cell limits in x
ylims = np.arange(ymin+yoffset, ymax, dx)   # list of grid cell limits in y

DEM = np.empty((len(ylims)-1, len(xlims)-1), 'float')  # declares output array

for i in range(DEM.shape[0]):           # iterate over rows of final DEM
    for j in range(DEM.shape[1]):       # iterate over columns of final DEM
        bottom = ylims[i]               
        top = ylims[i+1]                
        left = xlims[j]                 # these rows just pick minimum and
        right = xlims[j+1]              # maximum of cell [i,j]

        elevations = xyz[np.where(((xyz[:,0] > left) &
                            (xyz[:,0] < right)) & 
                            ((xyz[:,1] > bottom) & 
                            (xyz[:,1] < top)))[0]][:,2]
        elevations = reject_outliers(elevations)

        if len(elevations) == 0:
            elevation = np.nan
        else:
            elevation = np.mean(elevations)

        DEM[i,j] = elevation
```

This works, but I have to do hundreds of DEMs, and each one has hundreds of thousands of points, so I'm looking at a week of waiting for my computer to power through this If I do it this way.  It also seems really clunky to me.  Is there a way to streamline this?

Comment: So for each x,y you have a z (elevation). Why not use interpolation? And if your xyz data are on a regular grid, then you will large speed gains.

Comment: Have you tried boolean indexing?  Just remove the `where` wrapper around the logical expression.  Not that it will save much time.  The speed problem isn't with the `where`, it's with the double iteration.  That needs to be 'vectorized'

Comment: @dermen I'm not using interpolation (a) there is a much higher point density than my DEM cell point density.  I need to determine an elevation value for each, say, 1m x 1m cell from sometimes dozens of elevation values.  (b) The data is really noisy.  It's from multibeam sonar, which is basically a really precise fish finder.  As a result, pings are sometimes much deeper or much shallower than the actual bed.  To interpolate points based on adjacent points would potentially involve these outliers, and not involve the many other good points nearby.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm pretty new to python and so I haven't really built up my intuition around vectorizing.  Do you see an easy way to do that for this problem?

Comment: @TomAshley, you can accomplish this with interpolation - simply interpolate and re-sample at a lower resolution. More importantly, are the xy in your xyz array forming a regular (evenly spaced) 2d grid ? Because then you have lots of tools at your disposal to make this a speedy process

Comment: @TomAshley There are many inteprolation algorthms. not just nearest neighbors.  For instance, bicubic interpolation takes into account 16 neighboring points to each coordinate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation. It is in essence doing the averaging you are doing, and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to find the segment that the points fit into once and then loop through those groups so you don't have to keep masking the same elements over and ever even though they only belong in one segment.

One way to do this would be using numpy's built in searchsorted:

```
xmin = np.min(xyz[:,0])
xmax = np.max(xyz[:,0])
ymin = np.min(xyz[:,1])
ymax = np.max(xyz[:,1])
xoffset = ((xmax-xmin) % dx)/2.0
yoffset = ((ymax-ymin) % dx)/2.0

xlims = np.arange(xmin+xoffset, xmax, dx)   # list of grid cell limits in x
ylims = np.arange(ymin+yoffset, ymax, dx)   # list of grid cell limits in y

DEM = np.empty((len(ylims) - 1, len(xlims) - 1), dtype=float)  # declares output array

# Find the bins that each point fit into
x_bins = np.searchsorted(xlims, xyz[:, 0]) - 1
y_bins = np.searchsorted(ylims, xyz[:, 1]) - 1

for i in range(DEM.shape[0]):           # iterate over rows of final DEM
    y_mask = y_bins == i
    for j in range(DEM.shape[1]):
        elevations = xyz[y_mask & (x_bins == j), 2]
        elevations = reject_outliers(elevations)
        if len(elevations) == 0:
            elevations = np.nan
        else:
            elevations = np.mean(elevations)

        DEM[i, j] = elevations
```

When I profiled the alternatives already listed (after defining the reject_outliers to be lambda x: x) using timeit with xyz = randn(100000, 3) and dx = 0.1 I got the following times:

1. (your) where method: *10 loops, best of 3: 6.69 s per loop*
2. (dermon's) stepwise method: *10 loops, best of 3: 16.7 s per loop*
3. searchsorted method: *10 loops, best of 3: 2.11 s per loop*

However, if you're willing to use Pandas you can modify the code so that the double for loop is replaced by Pandas awesome groupby functionality:

```
elevation_df = pd.DataFrame({'x_bins': x_bins, 'y_bins': y_bins, 'z': xyz[:, 2]})
for x_y_bins, data in elevation_df.groupby(['x_bins', 'y_bins']):
    elevations = reject_outliers(data['z'])
    elevations = data['z']
    if len(elevations) == 0:
        elevations = np.nan
    else:
        elevations = np.mean(elevations)
    if 0 <= x_y_bins[1] < DEM.shape[0] and 0 <= x_y_bins[0] < DEM.shape[1]: 
        DEM[x_y_bins[1], x_y_bins[0]] = elevations
```

This lowers the time by almost another factor of 2 (*10 loops, best of 3: 1.11 s per loop*).

I should also note that it appears as though you are already excluding some points in your range due to your np.arange command. In the above I assumed you meant to exclude those points but if you want to include all the data you can use:

```
xlims = np.arange(xmin-xoffset, xmax+dx, dx)
ylims = np.arange(ymin-yoffset, ymax+dx, dx)
```

If you use these ranges instead you can modify my previous for loops to:

```
for i in np.unique(y_bins):
    y_mask = y_bins == i
    for j in np.unique(x_bins[y_mask]):
```

which lowers the timeit results of my previous searchsorted example to *10 loops, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop* which is at least closer to the Pandas groupby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
elev =  xyz[  xyz[:,0] > left  ]
elev = elev[ elev[:,0] < right ]
elev = elev[ elev[:,1] > bottom]
elev = elev[ elev[:,1] < top   ]
```

In this way, each conditional statement reduces the size of `elev`, so  each next conditional statement has fewer objects to consider. Still I suspect there is a better method. You could also try to search for the nearest x,y from `xyz` to x,y from `xlims`, `ylims`, and then back out the neighboring coordinates using `dx`, `dy`. If you can find a fast way to search then this might be your best bet (but you will need to take care when approaching the boundaries

### Aside

You can try [`scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html) if the x,y in xyz form a regular fine grid.

Otherwise you can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

interped = interp2d( x=xyz[:,0], y=xyz[:,1], z=xyz[:,2], kind='linear', fill_value=xyz[:,2].mean() )
DEM     = interped( xlims, ylims)
```

(it will be much much slower than `RectBivariateSpline`, but maybe faster than what you are doing)

You can change the `'kind'` argument to `'cubic'`, but it will slow down.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, while faster, interpolation lacks the statistical robustness I'm looking for.  This is because many of the xyz points have error due to the nature of the data collection method.  Not only do I need to average my points, I also need to be able to quantify error.

Comment: interpolation is one tool for calculating ```DEM```. Anyway, it is not removing any of your data, you still have all of the xyz points to quantify error. Anyway, this is actually way off topic, as your original problem stated something about conditional indexing :) I am adding that to my answer